# Ruby net-dns reverse lookups

Tags: ruby, dns, rubygems

I am trying to get reverse DNS lookups working with the net-dns gem for ruby.

From the rdoc

```
res = Net::DNS::Resolver.new
ip = IPAddr.new("172.16.100.2")
packet = res.search(ip)
packet = res.search("192.168.10.254")
```

should work but I'm getting

```
ArgumentError: invalid address
```

for the last two lines.

This happens using a custom gem built from head of github source or the latest released version from

```
gem install net-dns
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](http://github.com/bluemonk/net-dns/issues#issue/5).
It should be fixed soon.

Comment: It was fixed, very soon afterwards.